# Submit button has purple border around it in IE, but not in Chrome. How do I get rid of it in IE?

Tags: html, css, forms

My Submit button has purple border around it in IE, but not in Chrome. How do I get rid of it in IE?

Image: (Top one is in IE, Bottom one is in Chrome - I just cropped it into an image)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2k5KP.png

My code is:

HTML:

```
<div style="float:right; border:0px;">
    <input type="submit" class="submitorder"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.submitorder {
background-image: url('https://www.amleo.com/images/art/SubmitOrderSprite.png');
background-position: 0px 0px;
width: 205px;
height: 52px;
font-size:0px;
}

.submitorder:hover {
background-position: 0px -62px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're removing the border on the div, not on the input. Modify your CSS to the following:

```
.submitorder {
    background-image: url('https://www.amleo.com/images/art/SubmitOrderSprite.png');
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    width: 205px;
    height: 52px;
    font-size:0px;
    border: 0 none;
}
```

That should sort you out.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code
*border :none; / *for ie7* /

_border:none; / *for ie6* /

border:none \0/IE9;  / * ie9 specific not sure* /

Comment: Don't forget to mention it's for IE6 and IE7 :)

Answer (score 0):

i can't actually see the purple you are speaking of by it's a common problem with IE. 
You could get rid of it just by adding `border:none` to your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

First off, inline styles are never good practice.

As for the border, try:

```
.submitorder {
border: none;
background-image: url('https://www.amleo.com/images/art/SubmitOrderSprite.png');
background-position: 0px 0px;
width: 205px;
height: 52px;
font-size:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fore IE try adding `outline: 0;` & `border:none`

Answer (score 0):

```
.submitorder {
background-image: url('https://www.amleo.com/images/art/SubmitOrderSprite.png');
background-position: 0px 0px;
width: 205px;
height: 52px;
font-size:0px;
outline:none;
border:none;
}
```